# +/- Number increments in Shopify Cart

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing my first custom shopify web, but im trying to add a feature.

i need to implement a +/- number increment in cart quantity with text type instead number type (to delete the up, dawn arrows).

Like this:

[+- Number Increments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYCXz.png)

Here is the HTML input tag

```html
    <input type="number" id="updates_{{ item.key }}"
    value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
    data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801735/10761855

Comment: you might want take a look at this https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/How-to-use-plus-and-minus-buttons-to-update-the-cart-quantity/td-p/247862

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.number-input button:before,
.number-input button:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #212121;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.number-input button.plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: solid #ddd;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-input">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
  <input class="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
</div>
```

You can do this with css:

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
-moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
    <input type="number" id="updates_{{ item.key }}"
    value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
    data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}">
```